# passport.js logs in one specific user, even though other user's username/password has been entered

Tags: javascript, passport.js

I have the following code to authenticate users. When a username/password is not correct, `passport.js` doesn't allow to login which is as expected.

But when username/password is correct, `passport.js` always logs in one specific user regardless of the fact that another user's credentials have been entered. I wonder if anybody knows what might be the cause.

```
function authenticationMiddleware(){
    return function(req,res,next){
        console.log('req.isAuthenticated(): '+req.isAuthenticated())
        if(req.isAuthenticated()){
            return next()
        }
        res.redirect('/')
    }
}

app.get('/profile', authenticationMiddleware(), (req, res) => {
    res.render('profile.ejs',{
        user: req.user
    });
})
```

Console logs indicate that `passport.js` serializes the user whose credentials have been entered, however it always **de**-serializes one specific user regardless of entered credentials. I thought maybe my serializing and **de**-serializing methods are incorrect, but I couldn't find anything wrong with them:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('serializing user.username: '+user.username)
    //return user by id (automatically generated id by CouchDB is _id)
    done(null, user._id);
});
//
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    UserFindByID(id, function(err, user) {
        console.log('deserializing user.username: '+user.username)
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

### UPDATE

There was a mistake in my `UserFindByID` function. I corrected the mistake and now the code works as expected.

Comment: Did you check that the id passed is correct? print it out before the UserFindByID. Maybe that function returns a wrong value

Comment: @Kinnza I checked with `console.log()`: the `id` passed to `deserializeUser` and subsequently to `UserFindByID` is correct, I mean it is the `id` of the user whose credentials have been entered, however, another user gets logged in.

Comment: @Kinnza That was it. The `id` passed to `deserializeUser` was correct, therefore the only thing which could be wrong was my `UserFindByID`. I double-checked my `UserFindByID` and noticed a mistake. Corrected the mistake and now the code works fine.

Comment: Ok so deserializedUser gets the right ID and UserFindByID returns the correct user, right so far? Do you have some other configuration related to passport? to session? do you have these 2 calls:
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

Comment: OK ,great then :)

Comment: @Kinnza Can you make your first comment into an answer, so that I can accept that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that the id passed is correct? print it out before the UserFindByID. Maybe that function returns a wrong value